# How to match colon in sweet.js?

Tags: sweet.js

```
macro m {
  rule {
    $a: $b
  } => {
    $a($b)
  }
}

m 1: 2
```

I think sweetjs is interpreting the colon as a marker for match class. If so, how do I escape that make make sweetjs match it as it is?

This seems to work just fine though

```
macro m {
  rule {
    :$b
  } => {
    $b
  }
}

m :1
```

Comment: Thanks for making me me look at `sweet.js`. It's a pretty cool library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$[:]` to match a literal.